# Is there such a thing as "over-indexing" a database table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a new feature using new tables on a MySQL database. Is there a performance hit I get by indexing columns (that I'll use for `WHERE` in `SELECT` queries) from the beginning or should I wait until my table reaches a considerable size before I start indexing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to eventually need the indexes, you might as well create them with the tables.  This does somewhat slow down inserts, but they might as well be there if you are going to need them.  Why wait for slow queries, if you know the right answer?

One argument against putting them in right away is if the actual queries will inform the indexing strategy.  You seem to have a pretty good idea of what the usage will be.

Do recognize that indexes make some operations fast (notably `select`s).  However, they make other operations slower (notably, `insert`, `update`, and `delete`).  For this reason you should be thoughtful about the indexes that go on.

Comment: The problem with using index preemptively is it can mask bad logic.  Just fixed a bug where the index took a query from 20 seconds to 2 seconds and it was that way for a long time.  The problem is the query should only take a tenth of second since the join was unnecessary.  It should of been simple for developer to realize the join was not needed but the index allowed for acceptable time.   This is not the first time I have seen indexes mask problems or a developer lazily just add indexes.  Preemptively writing code causes problems.

Answer (score 1):

From [this related post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141052/how-many-indexes-is-too-many-indexes):

One more index than you need is too many. One less is too little.

> I've tried searching for a case where having too many indexes was a
>   problem and couldn't really find anything

You **KNOW** you have too many if your inserts are too slow, and the index used for reading   are not speeding things up enough to make up for it.

Answer (score 1):

When you insert, update, delete your table, the index need to updated too.

See this [Article about indexing](https://www.globalknowledge.com/blog/2012/02/23/disadvantages-of-indexing-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, inserts and updates could be slower because of an index.  However, in my practice this has not been a common problem.  You want to add only indexes that you know you are going to need.  Wait to add other indexes when addressing new problems.  One thing to consider is many times: “What if” indexes are forgotten, not needed and actually cause performance issues that can be hard to track down.  After finding the problem index, the developer has to spend additional time determining if the index is actually needed in some other part of the application.    As far as waiting to add indexes until a table reaches a certain size.  I would seriously doubt that would buy you any performance and if it did I would question the system design.